# func1().func2() what is this technique called?

Tags: java, spring-security

In spring security I see functions connected by `and()` and `.`(dot). So what is this technique? I've read through it before. But now I forgot, can anyone tell me a name so I can learn about it?

```java
http
  .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
  .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
  .logout()
    .permitAll();
```

Comment: That's called **Chaining**.

Comment: It's called "chaining".  But more to the point, it's an example of [Fluent Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: Yep,that's great for a beginner like me

Comment: It's Method Chaining aka Fluent API. Spring Security is a lousy example of it though - that API is _really_ bad and unintuitive. The fact that you had to manually format your code adding extra indentation is a good indication of bad design.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very vague description, but i think you are looking for the term [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes I forget the keywords I read